# Simplifying expression using pattern matching inside Assuming[]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, assumptions, canonicalization

I want to simplify a sum of terms that look like so:

```
1/96 (-48 I λ ℏ^2 G[1, 1] G[1, t1] G[1, t2] - 
   12 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 2]^2 G[1, t1] G[1, t2] G[2, 2] - 
   3 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 1] G[1, t1] G[1, t2] G[2, 2]^2 - 
   8 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 2]^3 G[1, t2] G[2, t1] - 
   12 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 1] G[1, 2] G[1, t2] G[2, 2] G[2, 
     t1] - 8 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 2]^3 G[1, t1] G[2, t2] - 
   12 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 1] G[1, 2] G[1, t1] G[2, 2] G[2, 
     t2] - 12 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 1] G[1, 2]^2 G[2, t1] G[2, 
     t2] + 24 I λ ℏ^2 G[2, 2] G[2, t1] G[2, t2])
```

Simplification should be acheived by using the fact that product of G's terms that differ only by exchange of 1 and 2 are equal as well as each G is symmetric in its two arguments i.e. $G[1,2]=G[2,1]$

So,
$ G[t1,1]G[1,2]^3G[t1,2]=G[t1,2]G[1,2]^3G[t1,1]$

Please help.

**Edit 1:**

I scraped off my earlier code as I just realized it was completely wrong. Also,
I am sorry for not being clearer. **Exchange symmetry has to be checked for each term of the sum as a whole**.

**Edit 2:**

Another try with no luck:

```
Assuming[s : _Times == (s /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1 }), 
 Simplify@(G[1, 1] G[1, t1] G[1, t2] + G[2, 2] G[2, t1] G[2, t2])]
```

Comment: `SetAttributes[G,Orderless]`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks for the nifty code for symmetry of G. What about the symmetry of each product expression as in interchange of 1 and 2?

Comment: That is much more complicated. You have to brute-force all permutations. This grows as a factorial, so don't expect any efficient approach. Why don't you use `FeynArts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should canonicalize each product of G's. For example:

```
SetAttributes[G, Orderless]

canon[term_Plus] := canon /@ term
canon[term_Times] := First @ Sort[{term, term /. G->switchG}]

switchG[a_,b_]:=G @@ ({a,b} /. {1->2, 2->1})
```

Your example:

```
expr = 1/96 (-48 I λ ℏ^2 G[1,1] G[1,t1] G[1,t2] - 
    12 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1,2]^2 G[1,t1] G[1,t2] G[2,2] -
    3 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1,1] G[1,t1] G[1,t2] G[2,2]^2 -
    8 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1,2]^3 G[1,t2] G[2,t1] -
    12 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1,1] G[1,2] G[1,t2] G[2,2] G[2,t1] -
    8 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1,2]^3 G[1,t1] G[2,t2] -
    12 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1,1] G[1,2] G[1,t1] G[2,2] G[2,t2] -
    12 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1,1] G[1,2]^2 G[2,t1] G[2,t2] +
    24 I λ ℏ^2 G[2,2] G[2,t1] G[2,t2]
);

canon @ Expand @ expr
```

> -(1/4) I λ ℏ^2 G[1, 1] G[1, t1] G[1, t2] - 
>    1/4 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 2]^2 G[1, t1] G[1, t2] G[2, 2] - 
>    1/32 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 1] G[1, t1] G[1, t2] G[2, 2]^2 - 
>    1/6 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 2]^3 G[1, t2] G[2, t1] - 
>    1/4 λ^2 ℏ^3 G[1, 1] G[1, 2] G[1, t2] G[2, 2] G[2, t1]

Comment: Thanks! This works just fine. Can you explain how the sorting happens in `Sort[{term, term /. G->switchG}]`,
given that it is not one of the common ordering functions like `Less`, `Greater` or lexicographical ordering?